# Do you hear the Writers sing?

Tags: discussion, graduation

I have just posted [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322781/386257) on Meta: **a call to end our imprisonment in "beta"**.

This has been done following [this](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1478/14704) discussion last year, and [this](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1744/14704) one this year.

If you care about us becoming a full member of the SE community, a graduated site, go to Meta and show your opinion.

Oh, and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdg_tD6FNGs) is for us. :)

Comment: thank you so much for a well-written and thoroughly researched post with all the receipts. (and they are STILL COMPLAINING in the comments that we don't need to graduate!)

Comment: And still complaining that our reasons for wanting graduation are unimportant (who needs migration paths?).  It's a terrific post and hopefully will move things forward.  We need to be the squeaky wheel.

Comment: Thank you! It needed to be done...